# How to improve this approach when I add a new object in a list?

Tags: c#, mvvm, prism, observablecollection

I'm using MVVM for my application.

This is my scenario. I've got a `ViewModel`, in it I contains an `ObservableCollection<Person>` and a delegate command for `AddPersonCommand`.

`Person` class contains FirstName, LastName and Age. In my view, I put three textboxes and binding each one to the person's properties. I.E.

- TextBox1: Binding FirstName
- TextBox2: Binding LastName
- TextBox3: Binding Age

So my `ViewModel` exposes:

- FirstName: string
- LastName: string
- Age: int
- Persons: ObservableCollection

And when I use the delegate command, I would be this:

```
public void AddPersonCommand()
{
    Person newPerson = new Person()
    {
        FirstName = _firstName,
        Last... ,
        Age = ...
    };

    Persons.Add(newPerson);
}
```

But I guess this approach is redundant. I mean I don't want to copy each property from the model, I supposed there's a better way to do this.

Comment: Can you restate the question? It's not clear what you're asking

Comment: Not quite sure if understand the question. Could you please clearify it with a sample?

Comment: Actually you need to bind a Person to a parent control of all those TextBoxes and after that you only need to add that Person object to the list. It will be already filled with TextBoxes information if you use Mode=TwoWay. Sorry if I can't undestood.

Comment: I've improved my question. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use FirstName, LastName, and Age in your view model. Just use a Person object. Then your code will just be:

```
Persons.Add(this.Person);
```

It looks like you have separate Person properties in your view model to facilitate binding. That's unnecessary. Instead of binding to the view model's LastName property, bind to the view model's Person.LastName. And Person.FirstName. And Person.Age.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but when I add the newPerson, always will be the same reference, isn't it?

Comment: Create another Person variable.